# matplotlib error while installing pyspeckit

Tags: python, windows, gcc, matplotlib, cygwin

While trying to download Pyspeckit (an astronomy program) I needed to get matplotlib for it to work. When I went to try and install matplotlib however, cygwin gave me the error :

```
In file included from lib/matplotlib/tri/_tri.cpp:8:0:
lib/matplotlib/tri/_tri.h:821:33: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
lib/matplotlib/tri/_tri.cpp: In constructor ‘RandomNumberGenerator::RandomNumberGenerator(long unsigned int)’:
lib/matplotlib/tri/_tri.cpp:2180:28: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
lib/matplotlib/tri/_tri.cpp:2180:28: error: expected ‘{’ before numeric constant
lib/matplotlib/tri/_tri.cpp: At global scope:
lib/matplotlib/tri/_tri.cpp:2180:28: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

So I was wondering if anyone might have a solution to this? I'm using python 2.7.3 through Cygwin so using the installer exe wont work.

If not, would it be possible to point me in a way to get something like canopy to be accessed from cygwin given canopy or similar packs have matplotlib preinstalled?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: These are just gcc compiler errors so there is probably something in the C++ code that gcc can't understand. Try looking at the lines of code that it says are errors and if you still can't get it, post a question with the C++ tag.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with matplotlib on Cygwin.

There is a variable  called "_C" defined in lib/matplotlib/tri/_tri.h on line 821 and invoked in tri.cpp on lines 2180 and 2186. For some reason gcc doesn't like this (is it a reserved word in some architecture?). I just renamed the variable to "_Co"  in both tri.h and tri.cpp, and the compilation finished successfully.

Comment: Did this lead to any loss of functionality or anything?

Comment: Or do you mean consistent renaming of all uses? If so, was it only referenced internally to that class?

Comment: No loss of functionality. Yes,  rename all uses (which are just the three I mentioned). Yes, I believe it's only referenced internally.

Answer (score 0):

The issue have been handled in the following ticket:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2463